# boost/asio async_read() TCP Server - Understanding io_service.run() on linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, asynchronous, boost-asio

Uh - another boost/asio question:

I am using boost/asio as a suggestion from my professor and did a lot of reading and learning about asynchronous operations. I already have a fully functional TCP Server with some extra weird features, which is totally NOT part of this question.

My real question:
As I was reading into async and writing my program, I often wondered about `io_service.run()`. First I make a call on `async_read();`, which adds work to the io_service. Then I want to run the service, but I would think the asynchronous concept triggers the OS to react to something and returning instant. If the event triggers the OS would send me a signal, which produces somehow a call to my handler. While all that happens in the background I want to be able to process things while waiting in the same thread as the call to `run()` was done. But `run()` blocks the thread, so I now have a multithreaded TCP Server with 1 thread per io_service, which seems dumb to me and I want further clarification before presenting this to my prof.

Is there an error in my program, if `run()` blocks after an async operation was started? Or is this the concept of asynchronous operations and you still need 1 thread per io_service? If the latter, can I add more than 1 handler to one io_service?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `io_service::run`, you execute the asynchronous handlers in the current thread.

This *is* the part which receives OS signals and calls your handler, and you *can* have more than one thread running it.

A common pattern is to start a number of `io_service::run` threads, and then call `io_service::wait` in the main thread whn you want to check if they have finished.

Comment: Ok, so far it seems my server implementation is a good implementation. What about the last question, how to add more than one handler to a io_service or in another way, pass the same io_service object to multiple boost/asio objects (boost::asio::signal_set & ip::tcp::socket)?

Comment: the constructors of both of those take a `boost::asio::io_service`, just pass the same io_service into both

Comment: Ok, I will try that.